# Styling with CSS2 when attr is not set

Tags: css, css-selectors

Styling an element with an attribute set is easy: `E[attr]`.

Is there any way to style an element with CSS2 based on the absence of an attribute, something like this  `E[!attr]`? (JavaScript solution is not an option).

For example, there are several class rules followed by id rule:

```
.abc {padding:1em;}
.def {padding:2em;}
#n a {padding:0;}
```

The html code is:

```
<div id="n"><a href="" class="abc">.</a><a href="" class="def">.</a></div>
```

Classes `abc` and `def` have lowerer priority against id-ed rule so both `a` have padding 0. I can't change the sequence of rules above, but I can change id-ed rule add my own rules. I want to avoid writing rules like `#n a.abc` for every class (there're many). Instead I need something like `#n a[!class]` to keep all class-ed `a`s intact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, not in CSS2.  The best you can do is to cascade your declarations:

```
E {color: red}
E[attr] {color: blue}
```

But even this can't really be relied on, as IE6 doesn't honour attribute selectors.

In CSS3, though, there is the lovely ":not" pseudo selector (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation).

EDIT

Thanks for clarifying.  How about:

```
.abc {padding:1em; !important} .def{padding:2em; !important}

#n a{padding: 1em}
```

Comment: @graphicdivine Thanks. Apology, I didn't express myself clearly in first place. Please look at the updated post. The above trick is good, but will not work in my case.

Comment: @graphicdivine Thanks! Completely forgot about this one - worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done in CSS2. In CSS3, you'd use the ["not" syntax](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/):

```
input:not([type="file"])
```

Comment: @jvenema Thank you, but I cannot use CSS3 at the moment.